# saga api call error - Payload: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to make calls to a Parse Server (RESP API) but I am having problems returning a payload. In my sagas.js, login function I am trying to set payload as seen in line 79 but it returns payload as undefined. Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

This are what my functions/files look like

https://gist.github.com/BruhKofi/9e0c7170830142c61f7833d9e80ea647

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here you can find an example on how I make an API call hope it helps.
https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/blob/master/login-react/react-login-front-end-app/app/containers/AuthPage/saga.js

Comment: @soupette thanks. This helped

Comment: You should use the request helper in your project it will save you a lot of development time